# How to manages multiple lable in single row but no. of cell in table view depends on array in iPhone SDK.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I want to display output like this:

For that used two sections. 1st one is for heading, 2nd for displaying the data, but in date column dates are dynamic b'cos it depends on the parsing data means no of row is depends upon that array.

So can anyone suggest me, how can I put multiple labels in single row for that following is my code: in   **CellForRowAtIndexPath ()**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 

    {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    }

    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        [cell addColumn:130];

        label =[[[UILabel   alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 64.0, 45)]  autorelease]; 

        //label.tag = LABEL_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
        label.text = @"Date";//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        label.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 


        //[cell addColumn:200];
        label1 =[[UILabel   alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(66, 0, 64.0, 45)] ; 


        //label1.tag = VALUE_TAG; 
        label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
        // add some silly value
        //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label1.text = @"Gold";
        label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
        label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];




        label2 =[[UILabel   alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(132.0, 0, 64, 45)] ; 
        //[cell addColumn:260];
        label2.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
        label2.text = @"Silver";
        label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
        label2.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];




        label3 =[[UILabel   alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198.0, 0, 62, 45)] ; 
        //  [cell addColumn:350];
        label3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
        label3.text =@"Bronze";
        label3.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
        label3.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label3];



        label4 =[[UILabel   alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(262.0, 0, 61, 45)] ; 
        //  [cell addColumn:350];
        label4.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
        label4.text =@"Avg Conf";
        label4.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
        label4.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label4];



    }

    else  
    {label5 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 64.0, 150)]; 
    label5.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
    label5.numberOfLines=4;
     label5.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label5.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    label5.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    label5.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label5];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

[image]
and outPut will appear according to 2nd image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAdPy.png)

[image: OutPut Screen According to code in CellForRowAtIndex()]

Comment: only dates are dynamic or other labels are also dynamic...

Comment: How is `MyTableCell` defined?

Comment: @spypriyanka u got solution for this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create CustomTableViewCell.
Where in the nib file one can easily draw the desired output Cell.(more than 1 label, adding image etc).

[From here you can take the sample.](http://www.e-string.com/comment/reply/9)

More for your give example, create two custom cells 1 for header and 1 for all data to show. Where as your data is NSArray of NSArray.